# Function to check if string is uppercase that is not a method

Tags: python, function, oop, methods

I'm writing a program that checks if a given password has at least 1 upper case letter and 1 lower case letter. I could easily check that like this:

```
    #Password needs to have at least 1 upper case letter
    has_upper_letter = False
    for letter in password:
        if letter.isupper():
            has_upper_letter = True
            break
    if not has_upper_letter:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("The password needs to have at least 1 upper case letter"))

    #Password needs to have at least 1 lower case letter
    has_lower_letter = False
    for letter in password:
        if letter.islower():
            has_lower_letter = True
            break
    if not has_lower_letter:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("The password needs to have at least 1 lower case letter"))
```

But this code is repetitive. I want to only write the logic in checking the letters for a certain kind of letter once. My idea is to write a function that takes the `isupper()` or `islower()` function as an argument. The problem though, is that the `isupper()` and `islower()` methods exist as a method on the strings themselves. If I could only get a function that **takes the string that I want to check** as its argument, my problem would be solved. Is there such a thing? Feel free to post better solutions to my problem.

Comment: by the way, I do not recommend this kind of password checks. A relatively long (>11 chars) minimum length and prohibition of simple repititions are easier on users and more secure than e.g. 6 words with at least one upper and one lower case character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`operator.methodcaller()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller), or you can use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr); either can be used to call a method dynamically:

```
from operator import methodcaller

def matches_test(test, password):
    return any(map(test, password))

has_lower_letter = matches_test(methodcaller('islower'), password)
has_upper_letter = matches_test(methodcaller('isupper'), password)
```

`methodcaller()` calls the named method on anything you pass to it:

```
>>> from operator import methodcaller
>>> upper = methodcaller('isupper')
>>> upper('ABC')
True
>>> upper('abc')
False
```

`methodcaller()` objects also accept additional arguments to pass in, so `methodcaller('foo', 42)` would call `.foo(42)` on any object you pass to it.

The [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) is just a (much more compact) way of writing your `for` loop with `if` test and `break`; it loops through the iterable you pass in and stops the moment a `True` result is produced; if no `True` result is ever produced, `False` is returned.

`getattr()` lets you access variable attributes; methods are just attributes you call:

```
def matches_test(methodname, password):
    return any(getattr(l, methodname)() for l in password)

has_lower_letter = matches_test('islower', password)
has_upper_letter = matches_test('isupper', password)
```

You can also pass in an *unbound string method*, so `str.isupper` or `str.islower`; passing in a new string value is like binding the method to that string:

```
>>> str.isupper('ABC')
True
```

So the following also works:

```
def matches_test(test, password):
    return any(test(l) for l in password)

has_lower_letter = matches_test(str.islower, password)
has_upper_letter = matches_test(str.isupper, password)
```

Comment: Unless you're trying  to keep it Python 2 compatible - one could just pass it `str.islower` and `str.isupper`...

Comment: @JonClements: also an option, I'll expand.

Comment: um, as much as I sometimes like the `operator` module, a simple `upper = lambda thing: thing.isupper()` would be shorter, not need an import, imho (but that's really just a ho) clearer :)

Comment: @Martijn yeah... if one's only ever going to be working with a `str` then it's quite convenient - otherwise, it's a no-go.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: `str.isupper` is shorter still, but a `methodcaller()` is more flexible in that you can add arguments.

Comment: ha! Who am I to argue with Martijn over python, but whatabout `findinstring = lambda s, *args: s.find(*args)`?

Comment: @MarcusMüller: but then the *caller of the lambda* has to provide those values. It'd be `lambda s: s.find(42)` instead.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: and a `methodcaller` is faster, especially when calling native methods on native objects, because no new Python frame has to be constructed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh, I didn't know that! Sounds pretty magic to me. Will have to read source code to grok how it's done. Thanks!

Comment: ah, OK, it's just a pyobject that stores the callable object and arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a lambda expression:

```
def check_password(password, f):
   return any(f(i) for i in password)

print(check_password("theString", lambda x:x.isupper()))
```

Or, pass the desired string method to the function:

```
print(check_password("theString", str.isupper))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach to this problem would be to use a regular expression.  The following code will validate a password with the rules:

- Password must be between 8 and 16 characters
- Password must contain upper and lower case letters
- Password must contain a digit

Code:

```
import re

def pswd_check(pswd):
    m=re.match("(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,16}$", pswd)
    return m!=None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(pswd_check("testthis"))
    print(pswd_check("t3sttHis"))
```

Output:

```
False
True
```